# Status bar has no shadow

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop

I have tried to move my content below the status bar with success. Used the following code:

```
<resources>
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">true</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

But the issue is that i have no status bar shadow. How do i achieve it?
[image: my result]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**shadows_bottom.xml** design and color the way you like it to be

```
<item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@drawable/shadows_bottom</item>
```

**Example shadows_bottom.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item >
    <shape 
        android:shape="rectangle">
    <solid android:color="@android:color/darker_gray" />
    <corners android:radius="5dp"/>
    </shape>
</item>
<item android:right="1dp" android:left="1dp" android:bottom="2dp">
    <shape 
        android:shape="rectangle">
    <solid android:color="@android:color/white"/>
    <corners android:radius="5dp"/>
    </shape>
</item>
</layer-list>
```

And you also need to set **colorPrimary** and **colorPrimaryDark** following official guidelines

**here:** https://www.materialpalette.com

Comment: Thanks. I set the height of drawable to 24dp. Is that correct? I mean the height to cover the status bar

Comment: It depends  on the output...if its not you are looking for than try manipulating it to get what you are looking for

Answer (score 1):

Add this line in your style.xml code theme:

```
<item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
```

Comment: are you using `setSupportActionBar()` or `ToolBar`?

Comment: Yes. toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.tool_bar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

Comment: I can't. I set toolbar in the code, thus it gives error "This Activity already has an action bar supplied by the window decor."

Comment: are you using extends AppCompatActivity in your MainActivity, right?

Answer (score 0):

In Api > lollipop you can set statusBar color, and it haven't any shadows.
Just write in your xml with theme:

```
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/toolbar_color</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/status_bar_color</item>
```